# Testing `IF EXISTS` in bigquery and exporting that information only if it exists

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to export some tables to a GCP bucket from BQ. I need to export those tables if and only if they exist.

I can't do this normally in BQ Editor since I have multiple export commands with `overwrite=true` and a specific `uri`.

My current approach is to use `IF EXISTS(select * from A)` and then `EXPORT DATA ... AS select * from A)`.

Will this increase computation costs significantly? AFAIK BQ caches queries.
Is there a workaround?

Comment: It may query twice the amount. Please check this in your personal history. Caching is only done for small queries outputs. For the test `if extist()` you could limit the amount of row to query.

Comment: Your logic is with `IF EXIST` is done 100% with `sql` ?